# YUI AutoComplete itemSelect - how do I know which key was pressed to do selection?

Tags: yui, yui-autocomplete

I have a handler for itemSelectEvent that gets called when an option is selected from the drop down. According to YUI documentation, this is fired when an item is selected via mouse click, ENTER key, or TAB key. Inside my handler, how can I find out which of these three options fired my handler? The handler takes two parameters: 1) the type, which is "itemSelect", and the args, which have the AutoComplete instance and some other stuff. I see the AutoComplete instance has a _nKeyCode, but its value is always 40 and it does not seem to change if I select an option using TAB or ENTER. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!